# What model should I use to predict a time series like this?

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, lstm, rnn

[image]

This series is calculated from the difference of two day's stock index. I rescaled it using sklearn's StarndardScaler.

It seems LSTM does not work well on this series.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms on sklearn are for tabular data.

If you want to deal with time series data with different algos, see [sktime](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/), or maybe you could provide more details of your LSTM script.